# Android Studio V1.0.2,Error:(2, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'?

Tags: macos, compilation, gradle

Android Studio 1.0.2 with gradle 1.0.0 on Mac

when I start a new project,gradle project sync failed with errors:

```html
Error:(2, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'My Application' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

**build.gradle under project**

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**build.gradle under app**

```html
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' android {
    compileSdkVersion 21 buildToolsVersion "21.1.1" defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.macernow.djstava.myapplication" minSdkVersion 14 targetSdkVersion 21 versionCode 1 versionName "1.0"
    } buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
} dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+' compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

And I also try online/offline gradle settings,the error remains.Please help me,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall Android Studio cleanly by

```html
rm -Rf /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.studio.plist
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*
```

And then reinstall it,everything is OK.